# Python odoo search query to check whether two datetime falls in between other two datetime

Tags: python, odoo

initial=2022-04-14 14:00:00
final=2022-04-14 15:30:00

case1:
t1=2022-04-14 13:30:00
t2=2022-04-14 14:30:00

case 2:
t1=2022-04-14 15:00:00
t2=2022-04-14 16:30:00

Want the python odoo search query to check whether initial & final time falls in between t1 &t2

Comment: You might want to add some more info, like where you want to do this check (in your model, database, or search field?) and add a code example of what you've tried yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Python example:**

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_1 = datetime.strptime('15 Mar 2022, 19:55 PM', '%d %b %Y, %I:%M %p')
dt_2 = datetime.strptime('30 Apr 2023, 13:45 PM', '%d %b %Y, %I:%M %p')
dt_now = datetime.now()

if dt_1 > dt_2:
   print('dt_1 > dt_2')

if dt_1 > dt_now:
   print('dt_1 > dt_now')
```

**Example in Odoo: in the "event" module:**

```
from odoo import _, api, fields, models

class EventEvent(models.Model):
_name = 'event.event'

date_end = fields.Datetime(string='End Date')

def _is_event_registrable(self):
        return self.date_end > fields.Datetime.now()

def get_date_range_str(self):
    today = fields.Datetime.now()
    event_date = self.event_begin_date
    diff = (event_date.date() - today.date())
    if diff.days <= 0:
        return _('today')
    elif diff.days == 1:
        return _('tomorrow')
    elif (diff.days < 7):
        return _('in %d days') % (diff.days, )
```